# Recursive how to return object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have actually found a solution for this but it involves global variables and no return statement.  I am wondering if there is a better way.  Basically I made a recursive function to search through registry keys and I want it to return the 'key' object when it finds the matching key.

Here was my first attempt:

```
import winreg
import sys

def parse_reg(key,find_subkey=" ",find_value=" "):
    try:
        num_subkeys = winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0]       #queries number of subkeys for this key
        for i in range(num_subkeys):                    
            sub_keys = winreg.EnumKey(key,i)            #gets the subkey name from index i
            sub_key = winreg.OpenKeyEx(key,sub_keys)        #subkey object from the subkey name
            num_values = winreg.QueryInfoKey(sub_key)[1]        
            for j in range(num_values):                     #this for statement iterates through the values of the subkey
                sub_values = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key,j)
                print("-"*len(sub_keys)+sub_values[0]+": "+str(sub_values[1]))
                if str(sub_values[1]) == find_value:
                    return sub_key
            print(sub_keys)
            if find_subkey in sub_keys:
                return sub_key
            parse_reg(sub_key,find_subkey,find_value)       #call the function again, this time with the new subkey
    except PermissionError as e:
        pass
        

reg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None,winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
key = winreg.OpenKeyEx(reg,r"System\CurrentControlSet\Enum")    
key2 =parse_reg(key,"VID_2C7C&PID_0121&MI_03")
print(key2)                 #prints None
```

I didn't realize that the recursive function returns to itself, so that did not work.

attempt 2, using a parameter to unwind the recursive function calls:

```
import winreg
import sys

def parse_reg(key,_return,find_subkey=" ",find_value=" "):
    if _return !=None:
        sub_key = ""
        return parse_reg(sub_key,_return,find_subkey,find_value)  #tried this and return _return
    try:
        num_subkeys = winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0]       #queries number of subkeys for this key
        for i in range(num_subkeys):                    
            sub_keys = winreg.EnumKey(key,i)            #gets the subkey name from index i
            sub_key = winreg.OpenKeyEx(key,sub_keys)        #subkey object from the subkey name
            num_values = winreg.QueryInfoKey(sub_key)[1]        
            for j in range(num_values):                     #this for statement iterates through the values of the subkey
                sub_values = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key,j)
                print("-"*len(sub_keys)+sub_values[0]+": "+str(sub_values[1]))
                if str(sub_values[1]) == find_value:
                    _return =sub_key
            print(sub_keys)
            if find_subkey in sub_keys:
                _return= sub_key
            parse_reg(sub_key,_return,find_subkey,find_value)       #call the function again, this time with the new subkey
    except PermissionError as e:
        pass
        

reg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None,winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
key = winreg.OpenKeyEx(reg,r"System\CurrentControlSet\Enum")    
key2 =parse_reg(key,None,"VID_2C7C&PID_0121&MI_03")
print(key2)
```

This one calls itself for ever.  And if I only have `return _return` it had the same issue as the first solution.

Finally, I decided to just use a global variable.

```
import winreg
import sys


def parse_reg(key,_return,find_subkey=" ",find_value=" "):
    try:
        num_subkeys = winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0]
        for i in range(num_subkeys):
            sub_keys = winreg.EnumKey(key,i)
            sub_key = winreg.OpenKeyEx(key,sub_keys)
            num_values = winreg.QueryInfoKey(sub_key)[1]
            for j in range(num_values):
                sub_values = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key,j)
                print("-"*len(sub_keys)+sub_values[0]+": "+str(sub_values[1]))
                if str(sub_values[1]) == find_value:
                    global key2
                    key2 = sub_key
            print(sub_keys)
            if find_subkey in sub_keys:
                print(sub_keys,find_subkey)
                print("FOUND")
                print(dir(sub_key))
                global key2
                key2=sub_key
            parse_reg(sub_key,_return,find_subkey,find_value)
    except PermissionError as e:
        pass
        

reg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None,winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
key = winreg.OpenKeyEx(reg,r"System\CurrentControlSet\Enum")
parse_reg(key,None,"VID_2C7C&PID_0121&MI_03")
print(key2,"hello")
```

I know there has got to be a way to return the value but I am stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!! :)

Comment: I think you've forgotten that when you make your recursive call, you need to return its result. Did you mean: `return parse_reg(sub_key,find_subkey,find_value)`?

Comment: I tried that in my 2nd attempt.  The issue was finding a base case to unwind it.

Comment: Maybe you need to check the 2nd attempt again. You still need to add a `return`.

Comment: In fact, strike that. Did you try the `return` with your first version?

Comment: yes, in the first version if I return parse_reg it doesn't return a 'key' object. in the 2nd version, i have a function parameter I set to the 'key' object and at the beginning I check if it's != None, and then return, but the issue is it will call itself forever

Comment: Can you produce a scenario which will work on my machine? I always get `None` even with your third example.

Comment: Read [_How to create a minimal, reproducible example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)